# Showing div when dropdown is slected and radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this `drop down` when I select that particular option I am given a `radio` button so when I choose the radio button I should be displayed a `div` and when I choose something else from the `drop down` menu that `div` which was shown should now be hidden

**index.html**

```
<select id="selection" name="sub_sel">
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="buttons" style="display:none;">
    <form id='form-id'>
         <input id='radio1' name='test' type='radio' /> Number1<br />
         <input id='radio2' name='test' type='radio' /> Number 2<br />
    </form>
</div>

<div id='select_raido1' style='display:none'>Div1</div>
<div id='select_raido2' style='display:none'>Div2</div>
```

**jquery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selection').on('change', function(){                        

        if (this.value == 'option_1')
        {
            $("#buttons").show();
        }else{
            $("#buttons").hide();
        }
    });
});

$('#form-id').change(function() {

     if ($('#radio1').attr('checked')) {
            $('#select_raido1').show();
     } else {
            $('#select_raido1').hide();
     }

     if ($('#radio2').attr('checked')) {
            $('#select_raido2').show();
     } else {
            $('#select_raido2').hide();
     }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/43rx29vj/)

This is what i have so far can somebody please tell me what i am doing incorrect

i am unable to display div when i click on the radio button and hide them when choosing a different drop down option

Comment: Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jitendratiwari/43rx29vj/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with :checked for radiobutton. Try like this:

```
$('#form-id').change(function() {

        if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')) {
            $('#select_raido1').show();
        } else {
            $('#select_raido1').hide();
        }
         if ($('#radio2').is(':checked')) {
            $('#select_raido2').show();
        } else {
            $('#select_raido2').hide();
        }
        });
```

Updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43rx29vj/6/

Comment: `.toggle(BOOL)` could be used as well!

Comment: any idea how i can hide the Div selected from the radio button when i click on the next dropdown option

Comment: Glad to hear that...!! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to make your elements more accessible by adding class names.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#selection').on('change', function()
{      
   if (this.value == 'option_1')
  {
    $("#buttons").show();
  }else{
   $("#buttons").hide();
          $('.mySelect').hide();
  }
});

    $('.myRadio').click(function(){
     $('.mySelect').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="selection" name="sub_sel">
    <option value="blank"></option>
     <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
  
  
 <div id="buttons" style="display:none;">
 <form id='form-id'>
  <input id='radio1' name='test' type='radio' data-target='select_raido1' class='myRadio' /> Number1<br />
  <input id='radio2' name='test' type='radio' data-target='select_raido2' class='myRadio' /> Number 2<br />
  </form>
</div>

<div id='select_raido1' style='display:none' class='mySelect'>Div1</div>
<div id='select_raido2' style='display:none' class='mySelect'>Div2</div>
```

Comment: this is also easy thanks for your answer :) appreciate it

Comment: @jake123, I tried to make less changes on your own codes

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code without changing anything in you HTML code check the example bellow.

**NOTE :**

```
$("div[id^='select_']").hide(); //Mean hide all divs with id start by "select_"
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selection').on('change', function()
  {      
    if ($(this).val() == 'option_1')
      $("#buttons").show();
    else
      $("#buttons").hide();

    $("div[id^='select_']").hide();
  });

  $('#form-id input').change(function() {
    $("div[id^='select_']").hide();
    $('#select_'+this.id).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selection" name="sub_sel">
  <option value="blank"></option>
  <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
</select>


<div id="buttons" style="display:none;">
  <form id='form-id'>
    <input id='radio1' name='test' type='radio' /> Number1<br />
    <input id='radio2' name='test' type='radio' /> Number 2<br />
  </form>
</div>

<div id='select_radio1' style='display:none'>Div1</div>
<div id='select_radio2' style='display:none'>Div2</div>
```